# Can we have a table inside column in openui5

Tags: sapui5

I have seen an example with something like this `http://jsbin.com/tibikonoqu/edit?html,output` Is it possible for the parent node can have child table with more columns than in parent. If not is it possible to keep table inside a column.

Comment: Both is not possible by default -- and would result in really bad user interface IMO -- but you could of course create a column cell template which holds multiple cells (a template with `MatrixLayout`, `HorizontalRow` or `FlexBox` with nested `FlexBox` items), and depending on the level you're in, render one or more cells in your template.

Comment: Don't do it. If you want to display more columns in the child element, add these columns to the table, and leave them empty in case of parents.
Alternatively, add only 1 additional column, and fill it with the child elements' additional data in a formatted text view.